# Why do Spheres with negative radius appear dark?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, lighting

If I run the following,

```
Graphics3D@{Blue, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Sphere[{3, 0, 0}, -1]}
```

I find that the positive radius sphere is properly lit as one would expect, but the negative radius sphere appears to always be lit from behind. Is this in the documentation somewhere? What exactly causes this to happen and is it the intended behavior?

[image]

Comment: The surface normals point the wrong way.

Comment: It is not a bug, it's a feature :)

Comment: The dark side of the moon